# Where do I put initialisation code for lambda (only executed once on cold start)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I use Python for AWS Lambda, we have some cold starts, and we need to ensure we do some initialisation when starting.

Is there a way to write some code in a certain method that is only executed once when the lambda  instance starts from cold?

Also, is there a way to do that only for provisioned concurrency instances?

Answer (score 3):

Global variables stay around when the execution context is re-used. That makes it possible to use a simple implementation like this:

```py
IS_COLD_START = True

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    global IS_COLD_START
    if IS_COLD_START:
        # Perform your init code here
        pass

    # Regular Code

    # At the end we set IS_COLD_START to False,
    # so we can us IS_COLD_START to check in other functions.
    IS_COLD_START = False
```

I don't think that's possible for provisioned concurrency instances. AFAIK the handler is only invoked there once an event appears, so it won't trigger this switch. Also, provisioned concurrency only makes sure there are at least n Execution Contexts around - they're still "normal" Execution Contexts.

Comment: Can't I do my init code here?

IS_COLD_START = True
***** INIT CODE*******
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    global IS_COLD_START
    if IS_COLD_START:
        # Log that it was a cold start
        pass

    # Regular Code

    # At the end we set IS_COLD_START to False,
    # so we can us IS_COLD_START to check in other functions.
    IS_COLD_START = False

Comment: Never try to put Python code in a comment - it doesn't work without formatting.